# Typescript error when introducing Abstract class or properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have a DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG that's defined like this:

```
export const DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG: {[key:string]:TopicCategory[]} = {}
```

We can get the `TopicCategory` array like this;

```
const values:TopicCategory[] =
     Object.keys(DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG).map(
     key => DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG[key])
```

When I extend `TopicCategory` with `AbstractTopic` I get the following error for the `values` variable:

> const values: TopicCategory[]
>   Type 'TopicCategory[][]' is not assignable to type 'TopicCategory[]'.
>     Type 'TopicCategory[]' has no properties in common with type 'TopicCategory'.

This is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-topic-category-error?file=index.ts)

I isolated it a little bit further.  The error is not triggered if there are no properties inside `TopicCategory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG` is a map from `string` to `TopicCategory[]`.

Your `values` is of type `TopicCategory[]`, but the callback passed into `map()` returns one of the values in `DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG`, which is to say, a `TopicCategory[]`. Hence, the result of the `map()` call is an array of `TopicCategory[]`, which is `TopicCategory[][]`.

I can't give any suggestions, as I'm not sure what the intended use of `value` is, or if the `DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG` has the wrong type.

There are two different solutions:

Either `value` needs to be of type `TopicCategory[][]`,

or `DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG` needs to be `{[key:string]:TopicCategory}`.

Comment: OK - Got it - Thanks - It seems so obvious now :)

Comment: I have an enum `SectionCategoryKeys` and I meant to get the values from that enum and use them to iterate through the `DOCUMENTATION_CATALOG`, getting the `TopicCategory[]` at each step.